# Playing .mp3 file in WP8 device not working

Tags: audio, windows-phone-8, windows-8

I am using following example to record an audio on Windows 8 app: http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2013/03/21/audio-in-a-windows-store-app.aspx. It uses the Windows Runtime Media API to record audio.

The example works nice but I have a problem. I use the example to record an audio, but if I try to play the recorded audio in a Windows Phone 8 device (tested on Nokia Lumia 820 and 920) using MediaElement control it doesn't work (I hear some noice similar to an alien conversation). It does work correctly on the WP8 emulator.

I have also tried to record an audio using the Sound Recorder app that comes with Windows 8 and I have the same problem: it doesn't hear correctly on Nokia Lumia 820 and 920.

This is the code I use the play the audio file in XAML:

MediaElement Name="media" AutoPlay="True" Source="XXX.mp3"

Do you have any idea why?

Many thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to save the recorded audio to a file, copy to computer and see if it is played correctly?

Comment: Yes, I have already tried that. It works correctly on desktop computers with Windows 8 (even on Windows 7). The problem is on the Windows Phone 8 device (Nokia Lumia).

Comment: I also tried to play the .mp3 generated file on an IPhone and it doesn´t work either...

Comment: Please post the code you are using to play the file

Comment: This is the code I am using to play the file: <MediaElement Name="media" AutoPlay="True"  Source="XXX.mp3" />

Comment: If I use the W8 Sound recorder app and try to reproduce the audio using the above code I get the exact same problem

Answer (score 0):

As I, and many, many others have posted on Stack Overflow already, the Media Element is really buggy and is not suggested for playing any source that is dynamic.

Instead, follow this blog post that I wrote on playing sound effects on the Windows Phone

[Playing SFX on The Windows Phone](http://anthonyrussell.info/postpage.php?name=6)

This is the executive summary of the post

```
static Stream stream1 = TitleContainer.OpenStream("soundeffect.wav");

static SoundEffect sfx = SoundEffect.FromStream(stream1);

static SoundEffectInstance soundEffect = sfx.CreateInstance();


public void playSound(){

    FrameworkDispatcher.Update();

    soundEffect.Play();

}
```

Comment: I cannot record a .wav con W8. This example doesn't work to play a .mp3 file.

Comment: Any other suggestions, Anthony? Thanks